# R: filter dataframe for multiple values, count and store results

Tags: r

Let's imagine I have a large dataframe like this

```
df <- data.frame(teams=sample(LETTERS,1000,replace=TRUE),type=sample(1:15,1000,replace=TRUE)))
```

I apply a very complicated filter to each team. I'm not reproducing all code of filter because it's not relevant to the question. I just tell you that filter containing multiple steps and based on special sequence of rows.

Very simplistically it looks like this. At the end I get two dataframes.

```
df1 <- df %>%
  filter(team == "A")

result1 <- df1 %>%
  filter(type == 3 & type == 10)

result2 <- df1 %>%
  filter(type == 6 & type == 12)
```

My goal is apply same filters to each team, count the rows of each result and store this into one dataframe.

Desired output

| Team | result1 | result2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12 | 6 |
| B | 8 | 2 |
| C | 50 | 10 |

It's necessary to apply filter independently to each team because I have **datetime** in original dataframe and use lag and lead function for cleaning the results. I do not reproduce full code here, so as not to complicate the question unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not exactly clear to me: I have changed the filter condition in order to get a meaningful result with the provided data:

In `subchain` we could modify and/or add filtering options:

But try this code:

```
library(dplyr)

subchain <- . %>% 
  group_by(teams) %>% 
  mutate(result1 = ifelse(type == 13 | type == 4, 1, 0),
         result2 = ifelse(type == 11 | type == 7, 1, 0))


df1 %>% 
  subchain() %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("result"), ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

output:

```
 teams result1 result2
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A           6      11
```